# Shader not working in Android - QT/QML Application

Tags: android, qt, qml, shader

Edit:
I am beginer in QT /QML and Android application developement.

Shader not working in Android - QT/QML Application

I have developer an application using QT/QML and ported the application into Andriod.

I have used shader in the application.

While deploy in Android shader is not working.

```
QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: 0:11: ':' :  wrong operand types  no operation ':' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;  // The coords within the source item                 uniform sampler2D source;         // The source item texture
```

**Edit**

```
ShaderEffect {
            anchors.fill: wrapper
            id:shader
            // Any property you add to the ShaderEffectItem is accessible as a
            // "uniform" value in the shader program. See GLSL doc for details.
            // Essentially, this is a value you pass to the fragment shader,
            // which is the same for every pixel, thus its name.

            // Here we add a source item (the scene) as a uniform value. Within the
            // shader, we can access it as a sampler2D which is the type used to
            // access pixels in a texture. So the source item becomes a texture.
            property variant source: ShaderEffectSource
            {
            sourceItem: scene // The item you want to apply the effect to
            hideSource: true  // Only show the modified item, not the original
        }
        property real dividerValue: 0.9
        // This is the fragment shader code in GLSL (GL Shading Language)
        fragmentShader: "
        varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;  // The coords within the source item
        uniform sampler2D source;         // The source item texture
        uniform float dividerValue;
        void main(void)
        {
            // Read the source color of the pixel
            vec4 sourceColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0);

            // The alpha value of the mask
            float alpha = (qt_TexCoord0.x>dividerValue)?1.0:((qt_TexCoord0.x>(dividerValue-.1))?((qt_TexCoord0.x-(dividerValue-0.1))/0.1):0); // = 0.0 at left, 1.0 at right border
               // float alpha = (qt_TexCoord0.x>dividerValue)?1.0:qt_TexCoord0.x/dividerValue;
            // Multiply the alpha mask on the color to be drawn:
            sourceColor *= alpha;

            // Write the pixel to the output image
            gl_FragColor = sourceColor;
        }
        "
```

Comment: Dude, you are 5 years at SO. Can you at least reformat this salad of code and clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 float alpha = (qt_TexCoord0.x > dividerValue)
                  ? 1.0 
                  : ((qt_TexCoord0.x > (dividerValue-.1))
                      ? ((qt_TexCoord0.x-(dividerValue-0.1)) / 0.1)
                      : 0);
```

The error is quite clear about the problem here: there's no operator `:` that would take `float` on the left and `int` on the right, which is exactly the case of the very last conditional, where the left side of the `:` operator (`((qt_TexCoord0.x-(dividerValue-0.1)) / 0.1))`) is `float`, but the right side (`0`) is an `int`. Just change the `0` to `0.0` (or `.0`) which is `float` and it should work.

I guess the shader compiler on the Android device is more picky about implicit conversions.

Comment: @Daniel : Thank you very much. This perfectly solved my issue.